# XML query on T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, ssis

Any help with the following would be hugely appreciated.

Below is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XML_EXAMPLE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Account Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Analysis 1 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 2 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 3 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 4 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 5 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 6 Code] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Analysis 7 Code] [varchar](15) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Within that table I am going to INSERT 4 rows. Two rows will have an Analysis 1 Code of 1000 and the other two rows will have an Analysis 1 Code of 2000.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XML_EXAMPLE] ([Analysis 1 Code])
VALUES ('1000'), ('1000'), ('2000'), ('2000')
```

What I am trying to get out of SQL is an XML format like below - note each Analysis 1 Code has it's own "Document" element, if you look at the CompCode. Each Document element, has a Header and Item (the rows in the table).

```
<DocumentBatch>
  <Document>
    <Header>
      <DocType>HR</DocType>
      <CompCode>1000</CompCode>
      <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
      <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
      <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
      <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
    </Header>
    <Item>
      <ItemNo>1</ItemNo>
      <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
      <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
      <Amount>Amount</Amount>
      <Currency>Currency</Currency>
      <Text>Text</Text>
      <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
      <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
      <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
      <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ItemNo>2</ItemNo>
      <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
      <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
      <Amount>Amount</Amount>
      <Currency>Currency</Currency>
      <Text>Text</Text>
      <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
      <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
      <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
      <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
    </Item>
  </Document>
<Document>
        <Header>
            <DocType>HR</DocType>
            <CompCode>2000</CompCode>
            <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
            <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
            <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
            <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <ItemNo>1</ItemNo>
            <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
            <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
            <Amount>Amount</Amount>
            <Currency>Currency</Currency>
            <Text>Text</Text>
            <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
            <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
            <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
            <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNo>2</ItemNo>
            <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
            <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
            <Amount>Amount</Amount>
            <Currency>Currency</Currency>
            <Text>Text</Text>
            <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
            <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
            <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
            <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
        </Item>
    </Document>
</DocumentBatch>
```

The code I have written only deals with one of those Analysis 1 Code. If you were to run this code - you will see it will only give me half of what I want.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              'HR' DocType, 
              x.[Analysis 1 Code] CompCode, 
              CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) DocDate, 
              CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) PostDate, 
              'Civica Cx Rents' RefDocNo, 
              'Civica Cx Rents' Text
          FROM 
              XML_EXAMPLE x
          WHERE 
              x.[Analysis 1 Code] = '1000'
          FOR XML path('Header'), TYPE),
         (SELECT  
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) 'ItemNo',
              'GIAccNo' 'GIAccNo',
              'TaxCode' 'TaxCode',
              'Amount' 'Amount',
              'Currency' 'Currency',
              'Text' 'Text',
              'CostCenter' 'CostCenter',
              'RefKey1' 'RefKey1',
              'RefKey2' 'RefKey2',
              'RefKey3' 'RefKey3'
          FROM 
              XML_EXAMPLE x
          WHERE 
              x.[Analysis 1 Code] = '1000'
          FOR XML PATH('Item'), TYPE)
      FOR XML PATH('Document'), TYPE, ROOT ('DocumentBatch')) row
```

My results - note I only have 1 Document element with the header and items for 1000.

```
<DocumentBatch>
  <Document>
    <Header>
      <DocType>HR</DocType>
      <CompCode>1000</CompCode>
      <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
      <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
      <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
      <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
    </Header>
    <Item>
      <ItemNo>1</ItemNo>
      <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
      <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
      <Amount>Amount</Amount>
      <Currency>Currency</Currency>
      <Text>Text</Text>
      <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
      <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
      <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
      <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ItemNo>2</ItemNo>
      <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
      <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
      <Amount>Amount</Amount>
      <Currency>Currency</Currency>
      <Text>Text</Text>
      <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
      <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
      <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
      <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
    </Item>
  </Document>
</DocumentBatch>
```

What I can't for the life of me work out is  -

1. How do I get `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1"?>` appended to the top of the XML format that I produce - as I will set this up via an SSIS package.
2. Where in my code do I place so that it ends up exporting both 1000 and 2000 as I am struggling where to place it. Have I constructed my code incorrectly in order to achieve what I am trying to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try the  following solution.

It is using SQL Server's XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

The XML composition is done in two steps:

1. Raw XML via `FOR XML PATH(...)`.
2. Final fine-tuned XML via XQuery FLWOR expression.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Account_Code varchar(15) NULL,
    [Description] varchar(50) NULL,
    Analysis_1_Code varchar(15) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Analysis_1_Code) VALUES 
('1000'), ('1000'), ('2000'), ('2000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT * 
    , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Analysis_1_Code ORDER BY ID)
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root'))
.query('<DocumentBatch>
{
for $x in distinct-values(/root/r/Analysis_1_Code)
return (<Document>
        <Header>
            <DocType>HR</DocType>
            <CompCode>{$x}</CompCode>
            <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
            <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
            <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
            <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
        </Header>
    </Document>,
    for $y in /root/r[Analysis_1_Code=$x]
    return <Item>
            <ItemNo>{data($y/seq)}</ItemNo>
            <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
            <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
            <Amount>Amount</Amount>
            <Currency>Currency</Currency>
            <Text>Text</Text>
            <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
            <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
            <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
            <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
        </Item>)
}
</DocumentBatch>');
```

**Output**

```
<DocumentBatch>
  <Document>
    <Header>
      <DocType>HR</DocType>
      <CompCode>1000</CompCode>
      <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
      <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
      <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
      <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
    </Header>
  </Document>
  <Item>
    <ItemNo>1</ItemNo>
    <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
    <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
    <Amount>Amount</Amount>
    <Currency>Currency</Currency>
    <Text>Text</Text>
    <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
    <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
    <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
    <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemNo>2</ItemNo>
    <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
    <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
    <Amount>Amount</Amount>
    <Currency>Currency</Currency>
    <Text>Text</Text>
    <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
    <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
    <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
    <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
  </Item>
  <Document>
    <Header>
      <DocType>HR</DocType>
      <CompCode>2000</CompCode>
      <DocDate>20211018</DocDate>
      <PostDate>20211018</PostDate>
      <RefDocNo>Civica Cx Rents</RefDocNo>
      <Text>Civica Cx Rents</Text>
    </Header>
  </Document>
  <Item>
    <ItemNo>1</ItemNo>
    <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
    <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
    <Amount>Amount</Amount>
    <Currency>Currency</Currency>
    <Text>Text</Text>
    <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
    <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
    <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
    <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemNo>2</ItemNo>
    <GIAccNo>GIAccNo</GIAccNo>
    <TaxCode>TaxCode</TaxCode>
    <Amount>Amount</Amount>
    <Currency>Currency</Currency>
    <Text>Text</Text>
    <CostCenter>CostCenter</CostCenter>
    <RefKey1>RefKey1</RefKey1>
    <RefKey2>RefKey2</RefKey2>
    <RefKey3>RefKey3</RefKey3>
  </Item>
</DocumentBatch>
```

Comment: `for $x in distinct-values(/root/r/Analysis_1_Codetext())` probably slightly faster. Also you don't need to `SELECT *` in the original XML, just the necessary columns.

Comment: @Charlieface, I concur with you. It was not clear what is the source for all the 'constant' values in the final XML.